# Random sound play on button touch

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want my button to play a different sound each time it is being touched.
For now the button plays one sound when it is touched.

I used the `onClickListener`,  and inside it I used the `MediaPlayer` to play the mp3 sound, the code is the following:

```
pressMe.setOnClickListener (new View.onClickListener (){

@Override

public void onClick (View v){

sound = MediaPlayer.create (MainActivity.this,R.raw.popup);
sound.start ();

}
});
```

What code should I use inside the `onClickListener`, so that if I placed 3 different sounds inside it, a different sound is randomly played each time the button is touched.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int[] arr ={R.raw.popup1, R.raw.popup2, R.raw.popup3};
final Random r = new Random();

    pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int i = r.nextInt(arr.length);
            sound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, arr[i]);
            sound.start();
        }
    });
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'Random' method and declare variable.using that variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Random class.

```
Random rng = new Random();
int choice = rng.nextInt(3); // this will get you random int with max value of 2
```

Then just make a switch-case statement for that 'choice' variable, playing a different sound for each case.